# Pandas add leading zero to column with both negative and positive values

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add a leading zero for all rows in a column. Here is what the column looks like:

| value |
| --- |
| -1 |
| 9 |
| 10 |
| -2 |

Desired output:

| value |
| --- |
| -01 |
| 09 |
| 10 |
| -02 |

I tried using zfill but it doesn't take care of the negative values.

```
df['value'] = df['value'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following :

```
    import pandas as pd
    
    data = {'value': [-1, 9, 10, -2]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    
    # Function to add leading zero
    def custom_zfill(x):
        if x < 0:
            return '-' + str(abs(x)).zfill(2)
        else:
            return str(x).zfill(2)
    
    df['value'] = df['value'].apply(custom_zfill)
    print(df)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With specific regex substitution:

```
df['value'].astype(str).str.replace(r'^(-)?(\d)$', r'\g<1>0\2', regex=True)
```

- `(-)?` - the 1st captured group to match the optional leading `-` char
- `(\d)$` - the 2nd captured group to match a singe digit at the end `$`

---

```
0    -01
1     09
2     10
3    -02
Name: value, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

For a generic approach, you can start by computing the number of `O`*'s* to pad (by using [`len`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html)/[`max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.max.html)), then grab the [`sign`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html) and finally use *f-strings* to form a single string :

```
s = df["value"].astype(str).str.strip("-")
M = s.str.len().max() # maximum number of digits

df["value"] = [
    f"{str(s).rstrip('1')}{v.zfill(M)}" for s, v in zip(np.sign(df["value"]), s)
]
```

Output :

```
print(df)

  value
0   -01
1    09
2    10
3   -02
```